# In CA, Old car registration/smog is Due, Can I sell the car?

Tags: car, auto-loan

In CA, Old car registration/smog check due at end of September, can I sell/trade-in end of August without paying? Do I have to tell the dealer/private party about this.

Comment: Its a 2001 Toyota Corola.

Comment: Why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

In California, you must get a smog check when selling a car privately. You usually do not need a smog check if you are selling to a dealer. Just tell the dealer it hasn't been smogged and they'll take care of it and/or adjust the sale price accordingly.

This web site has all the details:

http://www.dmv.org/ca-california/buy-sell/selling-your-car/paper-work-when-selling-a-car.php

Comment: Note that the site you linked to is not the California DMV (as stated with a big warning at the top of the page).  The info on that site generally seems to be accurate but it's not vetted by the state government of California.  A relevant real DMV page is [here](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/?1dmy&urile=wcm:path:/dmv_content_en/dmv/vr/smogfaq#BM2537).  It does not mention any exemption for selling to a dealer (nor does the page you linked to), although of course the dealer may offer to pay for the smog check themselves.

Comment: I've sold to dealers in CA and they've never required a smog certification. Private party you certainly need it.